# Energy at node of standing waves?

Tags: energy, waves, harmonic-oscillator

Is the kinetic energy and potential energy at a node in a standinng wave zero?

on one hand i expect if to be because there is no displacement but the prep book im using says it is at its max kinetic energy when the amplitude is zero on a string when its a standing wave

Comment: Both kinetic energy and potential energy are zero at a node.  As @Pieter has pointed out, the wording in the prep book is not precise enough.  Prep books have errors!  Watch out!

Answer (score 2):

When the displacement is zero, that means *everywhere* - the moment when string is straight. And its speed is maximal then, either up or down. (The book's "amplitude" is not quite the right word there.)

Answer (score 1):

Your prep book might be saying that for a general point(not a node) the kinetic energy is maximum at the mean position. 
While in case of a node it has zero kinetic and potential energies.